# async/await consecutive fetch calls: how to?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

As an example, suppose that i want to build a dynamic HTML pages showing the properties of all the planets and moons of the solar system, loading the data from an observatiry server API.

I do a GET request to get a json containing all the planets of the solar system.
I then need to loop each planet to write the HTML page, but i need to do a GET request to get another json object containing all the moons of a given planet.

So, my code looks like this:

```js
    async function GetPlanets(Star) {
        const response = await fetch('https://observatory.app/api/planets?name=${Star}');
        var data = await response.json();
        showPlanets(data);  // This function writes the innerhtml of a table, 
    }
         
    async function GetMoons(Planet) {
        const response = await fetch('https://observatory.app/api/moons?name=${Planet}');
        var data = await response.json();
        return showMoons(data);  // This function writes the innerhtml of a table
    }
         
    function showPlanets(data) {
        let tab =
          `<thead><tr>
           <th>name     </th>
           <th>mass     </th>
           <th>gravity  </th>
           <th>moons    </th>
           </tr></thead>
          `;
        // Loop to access all the planets
        tab += `<tbody>`;
        for (let r of data.all_planets) {
            tab += `<tr>
            <td rowspan=2> ${r.name         }</td>
            <td> ${r.mass                   }</td>
            <td> ${(r.gravity).toFixed(2)   }</td>
            </tr>`;
            
            // Now add the moons
            tab += `<tr><td id="moons" colspan=3>`
            tab += GetMoons(r.name); // GET the moons of this planet
            tab += `</td></tr>`;
        }
        tab += `</tbody>`;
        // Setting innerHTML as tab variable
        document.getElementById("systemPlanets").innerHTML = tab;
    }
         
    function showMoons(data) {
        let tab =
          `<table><thead><tr>
           <th>name     </th>
           <th>mass     </th>
           <th>gravity  </th>
           </tr></thead>
          `;
        // Loop to access all the moons
        tab += `<tbody>`;
        for (let r of data.all_moons) {
            tab += `<tr>
            <td> ${r.name                   }</td>
            <td> ${r.mass                   }</td>
            <td> ${(r.gravity).toFixed(2)   }</td>
            </tr>`;
        }
        tab += `</tbody></table>`;
        return tab;
    }
```

At the end of the `<body>` section there's the call to `getPLanets(Sol);` and the page should then show the data.

Now, i see that all the request receives an answer, but my page did not get built. I see the planet table for a brief moment and then it just show "undefined".

Searching for a solution I learned that async function cannot return a value, and also I think I've understood that the async functions should not be called in the way I do, but really i know nothing about promises and async/await so I'm struggling to get what should I do.
For what i'm understanding, I don't want to have all the request in parallel, instead i just want to process each planet/moon one at time...

How can i do all the GET requests after the first one and write the data in the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not *awaiting* the call to `GetMoons`:

```
tab += GetMoons(r.name);
```

Await it:

```
tab += await GetMoons(r.name);
```

Which means the function performing this operation needs to be `async`:

```
async function showPlanets(data) {
```

And it too can be awaited:

```
await showPlanets(data);
```

Comment: For @OP also note this isn't really "async" at this point, you're firing off `fetch` one-by-one and then waiting on each result. You could collect the promises returned from `#GetMoons` and `#map` them to their appropriate text, using `Promises.all` to determine completion of the entire array, and `Promise#then` to update when an individual promise completes.

Comment: @Rogue: If we want to get technical, it's "async" but it's just awaiting each Promise in serial rather than parallel.  Which the OP indicated was the desired behavior.  In terms of performance and user experience I'd personally opt for better parallelization, as I suspect you would too.  Though that may require more logical changes in this case.  For the OP's learning purposes though, this is a reasonable step in their progress toward understanding Promises.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the point about wanting it done in serial. I agree with your points, but I'll leave my comment for maybe further research.

Comment: @David, i thought that the "serial way" was better for the server (the real scope of this is a game, where some user put up some server to collect game data, so those servers may need some care about how much load to put on them). But i may be completly wrong as this all is way far from my field of expertise or education.

Comment: @Rogue, if you don't mind, i would like to see how your solution looks like, even if the answer for this question is the David one.

Comment: @Parduz: "Better" is a subjective term.  Awaiting these operations in serial does indeed send requests to the server at a lower rate.  So if that's a concern for the overall system, and if doing this doesn't significantly impact user experience, then a serial approach is certainly fine.